# Why does the dates filter does not work in a Pivot when recording a macro in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I have a sheet in Excel with a date column (dd/mm/yyyy)as follows:

```
A$Period Name
01/01/2018
01/02/2018
01/03/2018
```

When I look at the filter in the table I can see the dates as follows:

[image]

If I record a macro to filter this column I get the following code, which when I run it back it works correctly

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BP$5413").AutoFilter Field:=17, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "10/1/2018")
```

The problem I have it in a pivot on the same data set. The date filter in the pivot looks like:

[image]

When I record the macro the code lookslike:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name"). _
    CurrentPage = "10/1/2018" ' I tried with all dates. Showing Oct. here
```

When I try to run it back I get an error message in the last like like: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

I tried to change the date as dd/mm/yyyy (like the source) and dd-mmm-yy (like in the pivot) but it does not make a difference.

Any ideas on how to make it work? Also, I don't understand why when you record it the date it changes to mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I expect it'll work if you use the ISO date format:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name"). _
    CurrentPage = "2018-10-1"
```

Comment: That didn't work either, but I managed to make it work, (after testing all possible options) using CurrentPage = "1-Oct-18" (Format(DateVal, "d-mmm-yy"))

Comment: Your example failed for me, the one I posted worked for me. Dates are challenging when trying to set filters from VBA.

Comment: It seems a bit challenging, that is right. I noticed that if you record a macro and select multiple dates it gives you the date format you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps some one with a similar problem.

I managed to make it work doing the following:

```
DateVal = "01/10/2018"
DateVal = Format(DateVal, "d-mmm-yy")

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name"). _
    ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable41").PivotFields("A$Period Name"). _
    CurrentPage = DateVal
```